# How can I make this div appear only when radio button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I only show the vertical line when its radio button is clicked? I tried some code, but doesn't seem to be working.

```
  </<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('input:radio[name=angle]').change(function() {
        if (this.value == 'Horizontal')

        else if (this.value == 'Vertical')
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

  <h1>Grade me in chrome</h1>

  <input type="radio" name="angle" id=shapeh checked="checked" value="Horizontal">Horizontal

  <div class="parent-item">
    <div id="knob"></div>
  </div>

  <input type="radio" name="angle" id=shapev value="Vertical">Vertical
  </form>
  <div class="parent-item2">
    <div id="knob2"></div>
  </div>
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mwwgy0bs/1/).

Comment: Consider fixing up your markup first. That `</form>` doesn't have much of a purpose. Also some of your `id` attributes are not properly quoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a CSS solution (what's your intended browser support), you can use the `checked` attribute.

```
.control { 
    display: none;
}
:checked + .control {
    display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mwwgy0bs/12/

For a JS solution, we can apply a `data-attribute` to our `inputs` that set them as "selected". Then our CSS changes slightly to this:

```
.control { 
    display: none;
}
[data-selected=true] + .control {
    display: block;
}
```

Our JS would look like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $selected = $('input:radio[name=angle]').eq(0);
    $selected.attr('data-selected', true);

    // Set event binding
    $('input:radio[name=angle]').change(function() {
        $selected.attr('data-selected', false);
        $selected = $(this).attr('data-selected', true);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mwwgy0bs/20/

Since `[data-selected=true]` is an attribute selector, compatibility might be an issue. The solution could be re-written to use a class, like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $selected = $('input:radio[name=angle]').eq(0);
    $selected.toggleClass('selected');

    // Set event binding
    $('input:radio[name=angle]').change(function() {
        $selected.toggleClass('selected');
        $selected = $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mwwgy0bs/21/

Answer (score 0):

Change your if statement to:

```
if $('input[name=angle]:checked').val() == 'Horizontal'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can hide all the parent-items initially.
And if you have the same markup you can come up with something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Hide all the items
    $('.item').addClass('hide');

    $('input:radio[name=angle]').change(function () {
        // Hide all the items
        $('.item').addClass('hide');

        // Get the next immediate parent
        var $container = $(this).next('.item');

        // Display the image
        $container.removeClass('hide');
    });
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/mwwgy0bs/14/)**

Also I would fix the mark up first, by adding quotes in all possible places.
Then add a common class to the parent containers.

Comment: Another question if your willing to answer?

Comment: @JarriRodrigux sure. Shoot

Comment: ok so the grey blocks in my code are suppose to be scroll bars would you happen to know anyway i can make this possible ?

Comment: Do you mean to say that you can actually drag those blocks to simulate something?

Comment: yes but i have not clue what to use i tried using a slider method but that didnt work well

Answer (score 0):

Use `.toggle()` to hide and show the DIVs depending on which value is selected.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input:radio[name=angle]').change(function() {
    $(".parent-item").toggle(this.value == 'Horizontal');
    $(".parent-item2").toggle(this.value == 'Vertical');
  });
});
```

```css
div.parent-item {
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 25px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}
#knob {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-left: 25%;
}
div.parent-item2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 25px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  display: none;
}
#knob2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-right: 50%;
  margin-top: 165%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="angle" id=shapeh checked="checked" value="Horizontal">Horizontal
<div class="parent-item">
  <div id="knob"></div>
</div>

<input type="radio" name="angle" id=shapev value="Vertical">Vertical
</form>
<div class="parent-item2">
  <div id="knob2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this for hiding the div

```
if (this.value == 'Horizontal')
        {   
            $("#knob, .parent-item").show();
             $("#knob2, .parent-item2").hide();
        }
```

Check the  fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mwwgy0bs/19/

Comment: Coool thanks, but i have another question if your willing to answer?